# Positioning the text inside <label></label>

Tags: css, html

Dear community members,

I would like to position the text inside test in the center of a div. The code would look like the following:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 960px;">
<form>
<label for="test">Testing everything:</label>
</form>
```

Now if I try the following section of code:

```
<label for="test" style="width: 100%; text-align:center;">Testing everything:</label>
```

It does not center the text inside my main layer. Do I need to put a layer arround the label tags making it:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;"><label for="test">Testing everything:</label></div>
```

What is the standard method to accomplish that?

Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is very simple : label is not a block-level tag, which means that you can't give label elements a width. In other words, the width of a label element is the width of its content.

In your case, that means that it doesn't fill the entire width of your "test" div and then can't be centered.

To fix this, just add the following CSS property to your label :

display: inline-block;

This way, your label will be considered as a block for everything width (and height) related and your 100% width will be applied successfully, leading to a nicely centered text.